# window.open() parameters ignored when opening cross-origin window in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, browser, microsoft-edge

In Microsoft Edge, the following snippet will ignore the options passed to `window.open()` when `url` is a different origin than the current domain. But works it works fine in Chrome and Firefox, and when the domain is the same origin.

```js
const popupWindow = window.open(
    url,
    title,
    'menu=no,toolbar=no,width=700,height=600,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,' +
        'directories=no,location=no,screenX=0,screenY=0,top=48,left=48',
);
```

I found a hacky workaround to get the window to size properly but this is really annoying and you can see it redirect the page.

```js
const popupWindow = window.open(
    "/#",
    title,
    'menu=no,toolbar=no,width=700,height=600,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,' +
        'directories=no,location=no,screenX=0,screenY=0,top=48,left=48',
);
popupWindow.location.href = url;
```

How do I make this work on Microsoft Edge? Why is Microsoft Edge ignoring my size and other parameters? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to check the issue and it looks like security settings related issue.

I suggest you modify the below **Internet Options** settings.

(1) **Enabled** the **Access data sources across domains** option.

> Internet Options -> Security (Tab) ->   Custom Level -> Miscellaneous
>   -> Access data sources across domains ->  Set to Enabled

(2) **Disabled** the **Protected mode**.

> Internet Options -> Security (Tab) ->   uncheck Enable Protected mode
>   for Internet & Local Intranet

(3) Add both domains to the **trusted site list**.

> Internet Options -> Security (Tab) -> Trusted sites -> Sites -> Add both domains to the list.

(4) Uncheck **Require server verification(https:)**:

> Internet Options -> Security (Tab) ->   Trusted site -> Sites ->
>   Uncheck Require server verification(https:) ->   enter localhost url &
>   click on add button.

After modifying the above settings, I tested this code.

```
const popupWindow = window.open(
    "https://Bing.com",
    "Microsoft page",
    'menu=no,toolbar=no,width=700,height=600,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,' +
        'directories=no,location=no,screenX=0,screenY=0,top=48,left=48',
);
```

Output in **Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0** :

[image]

Comment: Any idea if there's a workaround if these settings are controlled by Group Policy?

Comment: If you are available to modify these settings via Group policy then I can try to find relevant policies. If you mean that these settings are maintained by group policies and you cannot modify it then I suggest you continue with your workaround as I did not get any other alternative way.

Comment: @Coburn, can you please inform the status of this issue? If the above answer solved the issue, then please try to accept the answer. If you found the solution by yourself then try to post your solution as an answer. If the issue still persists then let us know about the current status for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: This is probably the best answer for this case. No way to change Group Policy on my computer but this should fix the problem for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working correctly so the problem may be the version of Edge you are using. You can use [caniuse.com](https://www.caniuse.com) to check whether you can use things or not. However, since you have found this hacky way of using it you can turn it into a function like this:

```js
   function popup(url, title){
     const popupWindow = window.open(
       "/#",
       title,
       'menu=no,toolbar=no,width=700,height=600,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,' +
       'directories=no,location=no,screenX=0,screenY=0,top=48,left=48',
     );
     popupWindow.location.href = url;
   }
```

And now you can use the function popup.

By the way, I can see you are using ES6. Make sure your version of Edge supports const.

Comment: It does support const, v 42.17134.1098.0 is what I'm using. After further testing it seems to only be our internal domain that ignores the parameters... Using `window.open()` on `https://eprize.com` always ignores the parameters, no matter what site I'm on when I'm running `window.open()` (even if on `google.com` or `msn.com`). `window.open()` with `https://example.com` and `https://google.com` seem to work just fine

Comment: Nah, I don't think it's a protocol issue, I've seen no pattern between http and https causing the issue. After more testing there seems to be no pattern. Doing a `window.open()` on `https://eprize.com` of `https://google.com` or `https://example.com` seems to ignore the parameters again, so it's not just opening the one domain... I'm stumped

Comment: I just tried on my Edge and it worked for me. Most people don't use Edge anyway. Many Edge users are migrating to Edge (Chromium) or Chrome. Chrome, Firefox, and Opera are the big ones, there is not point supported the lesser used browsers.

Comment: After even further testing, the parameters are accepted between `eprize.com` and `merkleinc.com` but not between `merkleinc.com` and `google.com` (ePrize is owned by Merkle). Similarly between `force.com` and `eprize.com`, it works. It looks to be some sort of issue between Windows 'Trusted Sites' and non-'Trusted Sites' found in the 'Internet Settings'

Comment: And it is company policy to support Edge, so unfortunately there's no way around it...

Comment: Oh, I've dealt with that. Programming in IE and Edge is super difficult.